# Apple Script app help

Tags: user-interface, proxy, applescript, switch-statement

I'm trying to make an applescript based app that can, with only one click, activate/deactivate both Network and Adium proxy settings. The Adium part is done.
What I cannot do is to make a switch/if_then_else statement to chose between:
Network / Location: "Automatic" and "uMinho" settings.
The script should select the unactive option.
Any ideas ?

### Here is the script:

```
-- Activate Location "uminho"
tell application "Finder" to activate
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Finder"
    tell menu bar 1
        tell menu bar item "Apple"
        tell menu "Apple"
        tell menu item "Location"
            tell menu "Location"
 -- Need to switch between "Automatic" and "uMinho"
 -- Switch to the unactive one
                     click menu item "uMinho" 
            end tell
            end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

-- Activate adium proxy settings to all accounts
tell application "Adium" to activate
-- let's do this
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adium"
        -- open prefs
        keystroke "," using command down
        tell window 1
            -- open the accounts pane
            tell tool bar 1 to click button "Accounts"
            repeat with i from 1 to count of rows of table 1 of scroll area 1
                    -- tell group 1
                -- select the account
                set selected of row i of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
                -- edit it
                click button "Edit"
                -- end tell
                tell sheet 1
                    tell tab group 1
                        -- open the personal info pane
                        click radio button "Proxy"
                        -- change the name, if one was provided
                        click checkbox "Connect using proxy"
                    end tell
                    click button "OK"
                end tell
            end repeat
            keystroke "w" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

In 10.5 or later this will work, else you can use the command line utility scselect to switch locations.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell network preferences
        set currentName to name of current location
        if currentName is "Automatic" then
            set current location to location "uMinho"
        else
            set current location to location "Automatic"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I'm currently using 10.6.6. I cannot get that code to work.
I tried that instead of my first part of the code, and then just that code alone. It runs, but no changes.
Am I missing anything?

Thanks